# .NET Generics boxing compile error

Tags: .net, generics

I have this generic class

```
 public class BinaryTreeNode<T> where T : IComparable
 {
    public BinaryTreeNode(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public T Value;
    public BinaryTreeNode<T> Right;
    public BinaryTreeNode<T> Left;
    public BinaryTreeNode<T> Parent;
 }
```

and

```
  public class BinarySearchTree<T> where T : IComparable
  {
    BinaryTreeNode<T> _root = null;
    ...
  }
```

and static test method in test class as

```
  public static class TestBST
  {
    public static BinarySearchTree<T> GetABuiltBST<T>(List<T> valuesToAdd)
    {
        BinarySearchTree<T> tree = new BinarySearchTree<T>();

        foreach (T i in valuesToAdd)
        {
            tree.Add(i);
        }

        return tree;
    }
  }
```

Now, I get this compile error in this static method

Error   1   The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'DsLib.BinarySearchTree'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'System.IComparable'

What is going wrong here ? and when to add  after generic method name (GetABuiltBST**< T > **) ? Do i even need that ? I put that  after method name earlier to get rid of similar error, i didnt go in the detail that time.

If i remove , I get error "The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Btw, If i do not constrain T with IComparable then everything was working just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static BinarySearchTree<T> GetABuiltBST<T>(List<T> valuesToAdd)
```

needs a generic constraint that's strict enough to satisfy:

```
public class BinaryTreeNode<T> where T : IComparable
```

i.e. you need to add a constraint like this:

```
public static BinarySearchTree<T> GetABuiltBST<T>(List<T> valuesToAdd)
    where T : IComparable
```

---

As a sidenote, is there any reason why you use `IComparable` instead of `IComparable<T>`?

And IMO you should not have that constraint on your binary tree class at all. And instead allow the user to pass in an `IComparer<T>`. And default to `Comparer<T>.Default` which in turn uses `IComparable<T>` if the user doesn't supply one.

Comment: I used IComparable<T> but thats compile error. (and i read the reson somewhere) because T should implement IComparable and cant implement ICOmparable<T> itself.

Comment: I have a method inside BinarySearchTree class which is public static void PrintValueStatusInBST(BinarySearchTree<T> tree, T value) . Here i didnt need the constraint and not even <T> after method name (like PrintValueStatusInBST<T> ) why ?

Comment: In this specific case you need to implement it as `IComparable<BinaryTreeNode<T>>` The `T` of `BinarySearchTree<T>` and the `T` of `IComparable<T>` should not be the same.

Comment: "Here i didnt need the constraint and not even <T> after method name (like PrintValueStatusInBST<T> ) why ?" You don't need a `T` because you already get the generic parameter from the class in which you implement it.

Comment: sry. i didnt refresh your new comment. IComparable<BinaryTreeNode<T>> gives same boxing error.

Comment: Then you still haven't added the constraint to the method using your tree class. But as I already said, you should throw out the constraints entirely here and use a user supplied comparer instead.

Comment: If I am getting you right, then if I not apply constraint to Tree class then the boxing errors appear. Btw, inside tree class, for comparisons of T value i call another static comparer like                                                    public static bool IsEqual<T>(T x, T y)
        {
            return (Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(x, y) == 0) ? true : false;
        }

Answer (score 2):

Simply change the method to:

```
 public static BinarySearchTree<T> GetABuiltBST<T>(List<T> valuesToAdd) where T : IComparable
```

Comment: Do i need to add that same constraint at every method using T ? Isnt there any other solution. and 1 question i asked when to use <T> after method name ?

Comment: You need to add at least as restrictive constraints to every generic parameter substituted into `BinaryTreeNode<T>`. Without that requirement generic constraints would be pretty useless.